# How to maintain a many-to-one relationship of two tables based on postgis operations in PostgreSQL without Materialized Views

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have two tables, `device` and `block`, in PostgreSQL with a many-to-one relationship based on geospatial locations. Given the expensive nature of geospatial operations and the frequency of our queries, I want to maintain the geospatial relationship in the tables to avoid ST operations during every query runtime. when a block or a device's geometry changes, I need to update the block_id of affected devices efficiently.

I considered using materialized views, but I learned that many downstream PostgreSQL data replication systems, like DynamoDB in AWS, cannot sync materialized views, which also makes it difficult to keep track of history block and device association.

What's the best approach to achieve this without using materialized views?

Comment: For complex polygons, having a table of subdivided + indexed polygons can lead to huge performance improvements http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/11/subdivide.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use PostgreSQL triggers combined with PostGIS functions. This approach maintains the relationships when there are changes and avoids expensive geospatial operations during routine queries.

###### 1. Adding block_id to device Table:

First, add a block_id column to your device table if you haven't already:

```
ALTER TABLE device ADD COLUMN block_id INTEGER;
```

###### 2. Updating block_id Based on Geospatial Intersections:

Create a trigger function to update the block_id column in the device table based on geospatial intersections

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_block_id()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.block_id := (
        SELECT id FROM block 
        WHERE ST_Intersects(block.geom, NEW.geom)
        LIMIT 1
    );
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Attach the trigger to the device table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_update_device_block_id
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF geom ON device
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_block_id();
```

###### 3. Handling Changes in block Geometry:

Set up an AFTER UPDATE trigger on the block table to handle updates in the device table based on changes in the block table's geometry:

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_all_devices_for_block()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Update the block_id for all device records where their geom intersects with the updated block
    UPDATE device SET block_id = NEW.id
    WHERE ST_Intersects(NEW.geom, device.geom)
    AND block_id IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.id; -- input from @JGH

    -- Set block_id to NULL for device records that no longer intersect with the updated block
    -- assumption: the block.id is the primary key and never changes after a record is created.
    UPDATE device SET block_id = NULL
    WHERE NOT ST_Intersects(NEW.geom, device.geom) AND block_id = NEW.id;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Attach the trigger to the block table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_update_blocks_for_device
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF geom ON block
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_all_devices_for_block();
```

###### 4. Handling Deletion of block Records:

You'll also want to ensure that if a block record is deleted, the corresponding device records have their block_id set to NULL. For this, you can create a trigger function and attach it to the block table:

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_devices_for_deleted_block()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Set block_id to NULL for device records that were associated with the deleted block
    UPDATE device SET block_id = NULL
    WHERE block_id = OLD.id;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Attach the trigger to the block table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_update_devices_for_deleted_block
AFTER DELETE ON block
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_devices_for_deleted_block();
```

With this setup, you can maintain and update the geospatial relationships efficiently without relying on materialized views, ensuring compatibility with downstream replication systems like DynamoDB.

Comment: in #3 first update, you can add `and block_id is distinct from NEW.id` to the `where` clause to avoid updating unnecessary rows

Comment: not sure if there is any race condition for concurrent updates that I need to think about.